# Resolving objects in included files in Intellij IDEA

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, intellij-idea, phpstorm

Say I got an index.php file. It is a pretty basic html document with some php code. It contains some `<script>` includes in its `<head>`, in particular, it links the **jQuery** library.

I got another .php file that is also an html document, and it is included into index.php using the `require_once()` function. This file contains some jQuery code. But, since jQuery is not linked to this file, but to index.php, my **IntelliJ IDEA** can not resolve its code, for example, the `$()` function. So the IDE underlines it.

I am new to IDEA and I am not familiar with all of its concepts, but I believe there's a way to deal with that in such a powerful IDE. Or probably I should organize my project better? Please help me.

Comment: I don't know about resolving the libraries from included files, but you could configure your JS libraries as project libraries so that they will be recognized everywhere (or in defined parts of your project). Take a look at this article in IntelliJ's help: https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/configuring-javascript-libraries.html

Comment: Well, I tried adding jQuery as a library and setting the visibility for all the project and for this file in particular. That did not help, however.

Comment: this should work regardless of the file being included or not - having a javascript library configured should be enough. What JQuery version do you work with? Looks similar to http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-10908. I can suggest using JQuery Typescript community stubs as a workaround:
 in Settings/javaScript/Libraries, press Download..., select 'Typescript community stubs' from dropdown, choose 'jquery' there.
Note that stubs will only be used for completion, to get your code working in browser you still need to reference actual jquery file from your PHP